# Xcode 9: "An error occurred uploading to the iTunes Store."

Tags: xcode, app-store

Right after upgrading to Xcode 9, I was trying to upload my app and got this error:

```
iTunes Store Operation Failed
An error occurred uploading to the iTunes Store.
```

No error was specified. I couldn't find a rumor for what went wrong.

So I exported the IPA and used Application Loader (Xcode->Open Developer Tool->Application Loader).

This time I got a bunch of very strange messages:

```
An error occurred while starting bundles for the software update process.  Transporter will try to continue.  Unresolved constraint in bundle com.apple.transporter.asperasupport [5]: Unable to resolve 5.0: missing requirement [5.0] package; (&(package=com.apple.transporter.transport.service)(version>=1.9.6)(version<=1.9.6)) [caused by: Unable to resolve 8.0: missing requirement [8.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.util.backoff)(version>=4.1.0)(!(version>=5.0.0)))]
An error occurred while starting bundles for the software update process.  Transporter will try to continue.  Unresolved constraint in bundle com.apple.transporter.asperasupport [6]: Unable to resolve 6.0: missing requirement [6.0] package; (&(package=com.apple.transporter.transport.service)(version>=1.9.3)(version<=1.9.3)) [caused by: Unable to resolve 9.0: missing requirement [9.0] package; (&(package=com.apple.itunes.epubtoolkit)(version>=1.0.4)(version<=1.0.4))]
An error occurred while starting bundles for the software update process.  Transporter will try to continue.  Unresolved constraint in bundle com.apple.transporter.commlink [7]: Unable to resolve 7.0: missing requirement [7.0] package; (&(package=com.apple.transporter.foundation)(version>=1.9.6)(version<=1.9.6)) [caused by: Unable to resolve 8.0: missing requirement [8.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.util.backoff)(version>=4.1.0)(!(version>=5.0.0)))]
An error occurred while starting bundles for the software update process.  Transporter will try to continue.  Unresolved constraint in bundle com.apple.transporter.itmstransporter [8]: Unable to resolve 8.0: missing requirement [8.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.util.backoff)(version>=4.1.0)(!(version>=5.0.0)))
An error occurred while starting bundles for the software update process.  Transporter will try to continue.  Unresolved constraint in bundle com.apple.transporter.itmstransporter [9]: Unable to resolve 9.0: missing requirement [9.0] package; (&(package=com.apple.itunes.epubtoolkit)(version>=1.0.4)(version<=1.0.4))
An error occurred while starting bundles for the software update process.  Transporter will try to continue.  Unresolved constraint in bundle com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit [12]: Unable to resolve 12.0: missing requirement [12.0] package; (&(package=com.apple.itunes.epubtoolkit)(version>=1.0.4)(version<=1.0.4))
An error occurred while starting bundles for the software update process.  Transporter will try to continue.  Unresolved constraint in bundle com.apple.transporter.softwaresupport [13]: Unable to resolve 13.0: missing requirement [13.0] package; (&(package=com.apple.transporter.log)(version>=1.9.6)(version<=1.9.6)) [caused by: Unable to resolve 8.0: missing requirement [8.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.util.backoff)(version>=4.1.0)(!(version>=5.0.0)))]
An error occurred while starting bundles for the software update process.  Transporter will try to continue.  Unresolved constraint in bundle com.apple.transporter.softwaresupport [14]: Unable to resolve 14.0: missing requirement [14.0] package; (&(package=com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat)(version>=1.9.3)(version<=1.9.3)) [caused by: Unable to resolve 12.0: missing requirement [12.0] package; (&(package=com.apple.itunes.epubtoolkit)(version>=1.0.4)(version<=1.0.4))]
An error occurred while starting bundles for the software update process.  Transporter will try to continue.  Unresolved constraint in bundle com.apple.transporter.updater [15]: Unable to resolve 15.0: missing requirement [15.0] package; (&(package=com.apple.transporter.log)(version>=1.9.6)(version<=1.9.6)) [caused by: Unable to resolve 8.0: missing requirement [8.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.util.backoff)(version>=4.1.0)(!(version>=5.0.0)))]
An error occurred while starting bundles for the software update process.  Transporter will try to continue.  Unresolved constraint in bundle com.apple.transporter.updater [16]: Unable to resolve 16.0: missing requirement [16.0] package; (&(package=com.apple.transporter.log)(version>=1.9.3)(version<=1.9.3)) [caused by: Unable to resolve 9.0: missing requirement [9.0] package; (&(package=com.apple.itunes.epubtoolkit)(version>=1.0.4)(version<=1.0.4))]
An error occurred while trying to start the updater service. Exception's name: java.lang.NullPointerException, Exception's message: serviceReferences parameter cannot be null
An error occurred while trying to start transporter. Exception's name: java.lang.NullPointerException, Exception's message: serviceReferences parameter cannot be null
```

What can be done to solve it?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This story has an happy end!

I was trying many solutions from various forums, but the one that did the trick was very simple:

Open the terminal and run these commands:

```
cd ~
mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/
```

Comment: Awesome! Can somebody explain what this does? and why it worked?

Comment: showing this msg. "Directory not empty" in terminal what does it mean?. not working for me.

Comment: @ishahak getting this itmstransporter/ to .old_itmstransporter/: No such file or directory

Comment: @JalayOza did you include the period (.)?  and BTW: to those who missed the point, we don't really need the `.old_itmstransporter` folder, we are just forcing iTunes to recreate a new `~/.itmstransporter` folder.

Comment: I am getting the same thing: No such file or directory. It's not working for me, anything else I should know about this, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Some updates of MacOs and iTunes were pending in the App Store. I just updated all of them and the problem was resolved for me.