# While publish via Xcode: A downloaded software component is corrupted and will not be used

Tags: xcode, macos, store

While trying to publish an iOS app via Xcode, and after passing most of validations, I received the following error:

A downloaded software component is corrupted and will not be used. https://contentdelivery.itunes.apple.com/transporter/repositories/j2se8/1.12.0/bundles/com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit-1.12.0.jar

Actually, I'm running MacOS High Sierra on VMware

Comment: I got the same error, any updates regarding this issue?

Comment: Actually after resubmitting my app, the error gone!

Answer (score 27):

Goto Terminal (command-line) and run this command. This command updates the components from Apple server.

"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter"

Output of command show:
  INFO: Transporter is searching for new software components.
INFO: Downloading com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit/1.13.0...

Try to publish app now. Should work.

Comment: Works! you are awesome!

Comment: Had this after upgrading to Catalina and trying to notarize from the command line. 
This fixed it.

Comment: No such file or directory  
I am getting this error

Answer (score 4):

**For Xcode 11 and above**, Application loader is a separated app called **Transporter**

To update transporter components write this

```
/Applications/Transporter.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter
```

**Note:** If you encountered error like this

```
...
.......
<main>  INFO: indexing file: /Users/<YOUR USER>/Library/Caches/com.apple.amp.itmstransporter/obr/2.0.0/org.apache.tika.core-1.18.0.jar
<main>  INFO: indexing file: /Users/<YOUR USER>/Library/Caches/com.apple.amp.itmstransporter/obr/2.0.0/com.apple.transporter.aspera-linux-x64-3.9.1.2019-07-18-1737-EST.jar
<main>  INFO: indexing file: /Users/<YOUR USER>/Library/Caches/com.apple.amp.itmstransporter/obr/2.0.0/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.jackson-dataformat-xml-2.9.6.jar
<main>  INFO: Update check complete.
<main> ERROR:   unsatisfied requirement: com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit
<main> ERROR:        (&(package=com.apple.its.epubcheck)(version>=4.3.0)(!(version>=5.0.0)))
<main> ERROR:   unsatisfied requirement: com.apple.transporter.aspera-linux-x64
<main> ERROR:        (&(osgi.native.osname~=Linux)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64))
<main> ERROR: could not find the service with interface (com.apple.transporter.osgi.TransporterService)
```

write this command

```
cd ~
mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/
```

Then repeat the first command

References: [One](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46463779/1599713) [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54360362/1599713)

Answer (score 3):

Open termina and copy past
please use following command

cd mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter"

this is work for me.

Comment: Looks like you just created a backup before the download, so technically this isn't a different answer from the one above.

Answer (score 1):

see this update from apple:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58407699/585749

Available in the Mac AppStore

Transporter: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12

Answer (score 0):

Tried to re-upload the binary again and it worked without doing any changes to it :-) First time it did not, but the second time it was uploaded.

When uploaded, triggered this issue: 
ITMS-90381: Too many symbol files - These symbols have no corresponding slice in any binary [1563DEE7-9CA4-3E32-A685-59C6096A7559.symbols, 0C5A429A-9899-3DBC-B2BF-130063489259.symbols

Need to Google that to see it can be resolved!  :-) 
but it's just a warning, the binary was accepted.