# iTunes Store Operation Failed. A downloaded software component is corrupted and will not be used

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I got this error, while trying to upload archive to App Store:

> A downloaded software component is corrupted and will not be used.
>   https://contentdelivery.itunes.apple.com/transporter/repositories/j2se8/1.12.0/bundles/com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit-1.12.0.jar

I'm using Mac High Sierra, have all latest updates for Xcode, I'm not sure about which kind of corrupted software is error about.

Comment: Archive -> Select App store (not Ad Hoc).

Comment: Try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55751595/7301510). It worked in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the solution, I generated the project using `react-native`, when I wanted to test `iOS` part of the project on my `iPhone`, I found out that there was no support for the `OS` version `12.1`, so I downloaded zip archive for the support of version `12.0`, added it to `Xcode`, and forgot about it.

However, it seems that it's creating the problem during the sending app to App Store, so I deleted support for `OS` version `12.0` which I had added manually and restarted `Xcode`, after that `Xcode` started work as expected.

Comment: Not sure about the cause, but restarting XCode and doing a clean, build, archive resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a pending update of XCode. **Once I upgraded XCode**, the new builds worked fine.